# Cant inject autowire bean into my class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring bean defined, but when I am add the last 4 lines for Autowiring another RestClient rest bean, I am getting error (If I remove the last 3 lines, my spring container loads fine):

```
@Component
public class TimeseriesServiceImpl {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TimeseriesServiceImpl.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("MyService init method called");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destory(){
        System.out.println("MyService destroy method called");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restClient")  
    public RestClient rest ;
```

---

Error:

```
2016-02-07 18:46:41.609  WARN 11084 --- [main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timeseriesServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.RestClient com.tcs.timeseries.service.TimeseriesServiceImpl.rest; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.RestClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=restClient)}
2016-02-07 18:46:41.612  INFO 11084 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-02-07 18:46:41.623 ERROR 11084 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

---

I am using maven spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.tcs.timeseries.*","com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.config.*", "com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application-default.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { 
        "classpath*:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml"         
        })
public class TimeseriesclientApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeseriesclientApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(TimeseriesclientApplication.class, args);

            SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(TimeseriesclientApplication.class);
            ApplicationContext ctx = springApplication.run(args);

            log.info("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();


            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames)
            {
                log.info(beanName);
            }

    }
```

---

Details of the RestClientImpl bean:

```
@Component(value = "restClient")
public class RestClientImpl
        implements RestClient, ApplicationContextAware
{

    private static Logger                  log                  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClientImpl.class);

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    protected IOauthRestConfig             restConfig;

    private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

    private SSLContext                     sslContext;

    private ApplicationContext             applicationContext;

    static private final ObjectMapper      mapper               = new ObjectMapper()
                                                                        .configure(
                                                                                DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                                                                                false).setSerializationInclusion(
                                                                                JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    /**
     * 
     */
    static final String                    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";                             //$NON-NLS-1$


    private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolManager;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public RestClientImpl()
    {
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        setupSecureContext(this.restConfig.getOauthCertLocation(), this.restConfig.getOauthCertPassword());
        poolManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        if(poolManager !=null ) {
            poolManager.setMaxTotal(this.restConfig.getOauthPoolMaxSize());
            poolManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(this.restConfig.getOauthPoolMaxSize());
        }



}
```

Comment: Do you have `com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.RestClient` class in your classpath ? Depending on your build tool you should be able to see if jar containing that class exists or not. If you're using maven, use `mvn dependency:tree` to see if jar file exists

Comment: Is `com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.RestClient` an interface  or abstract class? If  so, does it have a concrete child annotated as a Spring Stereotype? (@Component, @Service..)

Comment: Did you enable auto-scan (<context:component-scan base-package="com...." />), Is your RestClient in your class path. Did you annotate RestClient with @Component("restClient") since you had explicitly specified it in @Qualifer ?

Comment: Have done all the above, I am calling a spring boot application and using Maven, I can see the RestClient.jar in Maven dependency too:

Comment: Restclient is an interface and has RestClientImpl as @Component with a Qualifier (value =restClient) in RestClient.jar  inside com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl.*

Comment: I even added <context:component-scan base-package="com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl, com.tcs.timeseries.*" />
 
 <context:annotation-config/> in application-context.xml to be double sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the profile declaration, in properties file where I need to mention as local. After I created application.properties file in config folder and put this line spring.profiles.active=local , it was able to inject RestClient bean without any issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `*` while specifying the `basePackages` attribute in the `@ComponentScan` Annotation.

So replace the same with the code below -

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.tcs.timeseries","com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.config", "com.ge.predix.solsvc.restclient.impl"})
```

This will properly scan the packages and sub-packages.

Comment: Removed the *, but still getting the error, if I remove the RestClient, Spring container is able to spin off TimeseriesServiceImpl  Bean properly and it shows in the list of beans spawned by the container

Comment: Can you post the code of  `RestClient`  and its implementation class? Also can you check the implementation class bean in the list of beans outputted by the  `log.info(beanName);`

Comment: I cannot find the name of the bean in the log.info